# Live Stream Tweets from Twitter using Tweepy. But With NO Filter

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to use Tweepy to stream real time Tweets from Twitter. I have the following code but I want to remove the filter attribute. I want to get the Tweet regardless of the filter. How should I do that ?

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time 
import sys

ckey = '<consumer key>'
csecret = '<consumer secret>'
atoken = '<access token>'
asecret = '<access token secret>'

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self,data):
        try:
            saveFile = open('twitDB.csv','a')
            saveFile.write(data)
            saveFile.close()
            return True
        except BaseException,e:
            print ('failed ondata, ',str(e))
            time.sleep(5)

    def on_error(self,status):
        print (status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey,csecret)
auth.set_access_token(ato]ken,asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth,listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is to change your consumer keys and access tokens. You should never, ever, share these.

You could create a filter with a geo code that basically covers the whole globe, or you could just use the statuses/sample endpoint if you want no filter.

Answer (score 0):

[As Andy Piper said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170152/live-stream-tweets-from-twitter-using-tweepy-but-with-no-filter#comment102724310_58170152), you can use the [GET statuses/sample endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/sample-realtime/api-reference/get-statuses-sample) using `Stream.sample`.